# How to put my java program up for download

Tags: java, eclipse

I made this java calculator and a text  based game using eclipse. what I want to do is have some sort of .exe or .jar file or anything that when I run it it runs my java program. I would like to be able to put this up for download so others can play my text based game without having eclipse. what I'm asking is I want my program to be able to run in browser or on someone else's computer.
I don't know why you would need it but maybe its in the code somewhere, heres my calculator code

```
package calculator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculator {


    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner test = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a number");
        int a = test.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter 1 to add 2 to subtract 3 to multiply 4 for divide");
        int t = test.nextInt();
        if(t == 1){
            System.out.println("enter the second number");
            int g = test.nextInt();
            int u = a + g;
            System.out.println("The answer is " + u);
        }
        if(t == 2){
            System.out.println("enter the second number");
            int l = test.nextInt();
            int m = a - l;
            System.out.println("The answer is " + m);
        }
        if(t == 3){
            System.out.println("enter the second number");
            int j = test.nextInt();
            int v = a * j;
            System.out.println("The answer is " + v);
        }
        if(t == 4){
            System.out.println("enter the second number");
            int p = test.nextInt();
            int z = a / p;
            System.out.println("The answer is " + z);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: [Deployment (Java)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to package the file as a executable JAR file. Please google it.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, my article "[Convert Java to EXE - Why, When, When Not and How](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html)" covers all the available options, from executable jars to Java Web Start to launchers/wrappers/installers to native compilation.

Answer (score 0):

BlueJ in my experience is best with this.

If you use BlueJ the classes switch flexibly, and adding them are not the pain in the butt NetBeans has.

Now for BlueJ jar file click "Project" -> choose main class -> I would click the two buttons of including source and BlueJ files in case you want to edit it later (so keep all the files together).

And you have it!

It is relatively quick and NetBeans again is very painful in creating JAR files.